# How to? Creating a webm video from kinect data for three.js example webgl_kinect

Tags: three.js, kinect, webm

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_kinect.html

How one creates a kinect webm movie to play in the above example, specifically, how one does it from an kinect oni file or a kinect point cloud?

Approach, language, os are not important.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello eight, welcome to SO.  Please expand your question to better allow other members to help.  Include code that is giving you trouble, and what you have tried to fix your problem.

Comment: There is no code that is giving me trouble. I am still looking for a code that would give me trouble. Did you read my question? Tx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alongside [kinect.webm](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/textures/kinect.webm) you'll find [kinect.nfo](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/textures/kinect.nfo) where I wrote some notes with links on how it was recorded.