# How to? Creating a webm video for three.js example webgl_kinect

Tags: html, html5-video, three.js, webgl, webm

According to this post([How to? Creating a webm video from kinect data for three.js example webgl_kinect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457765/how-to-creating-a-webm-video-from-kinect-data-for-three-js-example-webgl-kinect)), we need both webm and nfo files to run the example. I was about to modify and recreate the example with my own webm file, but it did not work well. It did not work well, so I even modified the name of my movie to kinect.webm, but it still did not work. Could anyone give me an advice? Here is the url of my test file > http://informatics-lab.com/senseable415/webgl_dummy.html

Comment: @WestLangley Thank you so much. Where can I set the size of video? In the code, I found this line: var width = 640, height = 480; , but I could not find 512x512 from the script. How did you know the size of it?

Comment: I found out the size of the video by viewing it separately and then "inspecting element". You need to physically crop the video.

Answer (score 2):

Your video is 604 x 512. That is not a power of two in width. Try cropping the video to 512 x 512.

three.js r.58